# Minimum Angular Velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, angular-velocity

> A bead is free to slide on a vertical circular frame of radius $R$ comes to equilibrium when $\cosθ = g/Rω²$.

The minimum value of angular velocity comes out to be $\sqrt{g/R}$, which we can find out by balancing  Gravitational and centripetal force with Normal reaction to bead from the frame.

Why can't the angular velocity have values between 0 and $\sqrt{g/R}$?

Answer (score 1):

The angular velocity can definitely have values in that range. It's just that you then lose that equilibrium position you reference.

If $\omega<\sqrt{g/R}$ then you only have two equilibrium positions. One at $\theta=0$ (the bottom of the ring) and the other at $\theta=\pi$ (the top of the ring).

If $\omega\geq\sqrt{g/R}$ then you gain a third equilibrium that you mention where the relation holds of $\cos\theta=gR/\omega$

Answer (score 1):

If your formula was correct, then the maximum $\cosθ = 1 = g/(Rω^2)$. However, it is not correct.  Assuming $θ$ is measured up from the (downward) vertical to the radius going to the bead, then:  $N(\cosθ) -mg =0$  and $N(\sinθ) = m(Rω^2)$.

Solve the first equation for $N$ and put it into the second.  Then: $(mg/\cosθ)\sinθ = m(Rω^2)$  and $(\cosθ)/( \sinθ) = g/(Rω^2)$.  The angular velocity is not limited.